# Using Kanban board for sprint backlog in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, task-management

I am wondering if there is a way of using the kanban board for sprint backlogs in TFS 2015.

When you click Board on Epics, Features and Stories it shows a kanban board that is centered around user stories. I would like to see that same board but filtering all user stories in for example sprint 50 (sprint backlogs are defined by us as Iterations)

When you click the Sprint / Iteration it shows a taskboard - this is the one I would like to change.

[image]

Comment: Did you just mean you want to change the task to userstory or still keep the task and add userstory in the position of the Board with red line? I have add a screenshot in your question, you could also add one to clarify it . And which process are you using  Agile, or Scrum?

Comment: I wanted to stop using the taskboard (your screenshot) and only use the Kanban Board, because here I have control of the columns and I make User Stories my main focus instead of Task. We use scrum, but for our team, the tasks doesn't really make sense. The user stories are small enough.

I accepted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not support in TFS2015. But with the latest TFS2017, You are able to filter the items in Kankan board by "Iteration":
[image]

Comment: I confirmed this today with a colleague and it looks like we will get 2017 soon. Thx.